# ClassLoader new class?

Tags: java, file, jar, classloader

I want load a file from a Jar, and I saw that I need use ClassLoader for that.

But the example that I saw use a class that I know that have inside...

I have this code :

```
File destino = new File(".\\archivoCopiado.txt");

try {
    InputStream in = Archivo.class.getResourceAsStream("Archivo.txt");
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destino);

    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the class "Archivo" is completly empty, and I dont know what I should for this work...

Comment: What is 'Archivo.txt' in you code? Can you share it?

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to do? Load a Java class; or load a text file?

Comment: Archivo is a File that I have in "bin". And I am trying to copy a File (.txt) from my jar, to other directory :)

I want make a .jar with a File .txt inside, and when I execute my jar, this file will be copied in "destino"

Comment: Your code seems to be correct, I tried it on my machine and it works. What is the content of your jar file? Is your `Archivo.txt` file at the root of the archive?

Comment: This is the problem, I dont know how make the jar file. Archivo.txt is in the project folder, in "bin", but I make the jar file and dont work... Ah, and I change "Archivo.class.getResourceAsStream..." for: "main.class.getResourceAsStream..." and in eclipse work well, but the jar fail :/